# Print mail item as pdf

Tags: vba, outlook

I am attempting to save all of the mail items within a folder in Outlook as PDF.

```
Sub pdfConversion()
    Dim outApp As Object, objOutlook As Object, objFolder As Object, myItems As Object, myItem As Object
    Dim psName As String, pdfName As String

    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objOutlook = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("PDF Conversion")
    Set myItems = objFolder.Items

    For Each myItem In myItems
        myItem.PrintOut copies:=1, preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="Adobe PDF", printtofile:=True, _
        collate:=True, prtofilename:="C:\Users\lturner\Documents\" & myItem.Subject & ".pdf"
    Next myItem
End Sub
```

I am using Outlook 2007, which doesn't have the option to save mails as PDF, hence I'm attempting to use the `.PrintOut` method.

Using the above I am currently receiving a "Named argument not found" error. I've looked elsewhere on the internet, but cannot seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used a combination of the answers posted by [Krishna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31403680) and [Eugene Astafiev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31407244) to produce the below code, which will now produce a PDF document out of the `myItem`.

```
Dim objDoc As Object, objInspector As Object
For Each myItem In myItems
    fileName = Replace(myItem.Subject, ":", "")
    Set objInspector = myItem.GetInspector
    Set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
    objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat folderPath & fileName & ".pdf", 17
    Set objInspector = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing
Next myItem
```

Posting this so anyone in the future who stumbles across the question can see the working code, which uses the `WordEditor` property.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use the **SaveAs** method of the MailItem class. The **WordEditor** property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document class which represents the message body. You can call the **ExportAsFixedFormat** method of the Document class directly from Outlook avoiding any disk operations. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks a lot for the tip. I'm trying to get this working, and am receiving "Object variable or with block variable not set" on the following line of code: `Set objDoc = outApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor`. outApp has been set as `Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` (for some reason my VBE always debugs if I attempt to early bind, that's why I've used late binding). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got it working now.. but thanks for informing me of this method of working with mail items.

Answer (score 1):

`MailItem.Printout` doesnt take any paramters. it uses application level default settings.

The workaround i can think here is 2 step,

Step 1
use `MailItem.SaveAs "somefile.doc", olDoc` to convert to a RTF or Document

Step 2 using word automation, (reference word objects 14.0)
 convert this to pdf using [fixedformat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb256835(v=office.12).aspx).

```
Document.ExportAsFixedFormat "somefile.pdf", 17
```

Comment: Why do you need to save the item on the disc?

Comment: And the header info? Sender to date? That is really importante and it is not printed out in the pdf

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if the original email is formatted as document that supports word conversion.

For instance if you are trying to print a Custom Form to PDF then this will fail because the Inspector will always pass back NOTHING for the word editor.