# Outlook VBA Print to PDF

Tags: vba, printing, outlook, ms-word

I would like to automatically print emails to PDF from Outlook.

I haven't found a way to automate the print dialogue. There are a couple other threads dealing with this same issue in Outlook VBA, but no clear solution (I thought it would be simple!)

For example, I have a rule in outlook that automatically moves receipts to a specific folder. I'd like to automatically print these to PDF. I've tried to accomplish this by...

1. For Loop: Go through each unread item in the specified folder
2. Print: `MailItem.Printout` Method
3. Print Dialogue: Input path and filename and click OK. I haven't found any means of automating this process.

```
Sub PrintReceipts()

'==============================================
'Declare variables, set namespace, define outlook folder (example names used below)
'==============================================
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Path As String
Dim Name As String

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("subfolder 1").Folders("subfolder 2")

'==============================================
'For each unread message save to Path with Name and mark as Read (path is just an example)
'==============================================
For Each msg In olFldr.Items
    If msg.UnRead Then
    Path = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\" 
    Name = msg.Subject & ".pdf"
  
    msg.PrintOut
    
    '=================================================
    'Here is where I get lost. 
    'Print Dialogue opens. I have tried SendKeys but it does not work 
    '=================================================

    msg.UnRead = False
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Alternative: I am wondering if I can do the following.

1. Save for Word: `MailItem.SaveAs`, to save the item as an .MHT
2. Open Word: Somehow open Word and apply `ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat` to export as PDF
3. Close Word and go back to Outlook.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402806/print-mail-item-as-pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print mail item as pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402806/print-mail-item-as-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea in Outlook. Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. These methods allow getting items that correspond to your search criteria only. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

To save the message body using the PDF file format there is no need to use the `SaveAs` method of the `MailItem` class. The `WordEditor` property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the Word Document class which represents the message body. You can call the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method of the `Document` class directly from Outlook avoiding any disk operations.

```
Dim objDoc As Object, objInspector As Object
Set objInspector = myItem.GetInspector
Set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat folderPath & fileName & ".pdf", 17
Set objInspector = Nothing
Set objDoc = Nothing
```

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this, worked like a charm! The Restrict method is very useful. 

Much appreciated